# É certo dizer: O português não tem tal costumes. Ao invéz de dizer os português... tem que ser os portuguêses não

Tags: nomes-compostos

É certo dizer:
O português não tem tal costume? Em vez de dizer:
Os portuguêses  não tem tal costumes.
Aqui dizemos o português, referindo a pessoa

Comment: O brasileiro é um bicho complicado.

Answer (score 2):

Está certo, sim. Podes ver isto por exemplo na [*Gramática de Usos do Português*](https://archive.org/details/gramaticadeusosd0000neve) (págs. 396-400):

> 3.1 O **artigo definido** como **determinante** do **nome**
>
> 3.1.1 Com **substantivo comum**
>
> Podem ser indicados como os casos mais gerais do uso do **artigo** determinando um **nome**
>
> 3.1.1.1 No **singular** ou no **plural**
>
> [...]
>
> 3.1.1.1.7 Junto de **substantivo** que se refere a um grupo ou um tipo, podendo-se entender que esse substantivo denomina o conjunto de pessoas do grupo, ou que ele se refere ao protótipo, ou elemento típico, do grupo (**referência genérica**):
>
> > **O geógrafo** não é mais nem menos capaz de elaborar uma síntese pelo facto de ser geógrafo.
> > **O banheiro** é o local ideal para se ler livro de provérbios.
> > **Os comunistas**, como **Os católicos**, têm uma grande preocupação da formação ideológica.
> > Nessa época, nesse períodos de recesso, **As tartarugas** geralmente não procuram comida.
> > Para **Os escravos** era muito difícil lutar e reagir.

As frases *o português não tem tais costumes* e *os portugueses não têm tais costumes* transmitem essencialmente a mesma ideia.